# how to set autocomplete text hint name scrolling or marquee

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, autocompletetextview, marquee

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
  android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:hint="@string/auto"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
  android:ems="10" >
```

how to set hint name scrolling or marqueeing in layout or class?

Comment: I have seen your yesterday question too. I have also faced same issue with marquee. And may bee its not possible with EditText, too. So can you tell me what you trying to achieve here, so that we can find alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here I do have find alter native for the same, the trick is a bit lengthy. But may be work for you.

**Step-1 :** Create your xml file like this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <com.example.mydemo.TextScrolling
        android:id="@+id/forHint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/long_hint_string" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Step-2 :** For TextScrolling custom text view which scrolls, I have used this class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983871/marquee-textview-not-working-in-android-layout).

**Step-3 :** Java file code depends on textwatcher and visibility show and hide.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

AutoCompleteTextView mAutoCompleteTextView;
TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forHint);

    mAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            Log.e(TAG, "arg0 = " + arg0);
            if(arg0.length()>0) {
                mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i want this code reason i used autocomplete hint name length too long. so using marquee user saw and understand easily

Comment: i implement this code but its not working.. not scrolling or marqueeing

Comment: Where you got stucked?

Comment: run program and also view text msg but not scrolling or marqueeing

Comment: Is your hint text message too long, make it long enough and then try it.

Comment: hey i want another one help if u know tell me. i click select date automatically age calulate and show txtbox. suppose i change age date button txt will be clear. but age diff only